# AWS DynamoDB TransactionWriteItem Retry Example

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

i'm trying to look for an example on how to retry whenever we get a exception out of dynamoDBMapper.transactionWrite. Thanks in Advance.

```
    TransactionWriteRequest transactionWriteRequest = new TransactionWriteRequest();
    transactionWriteRequest.withIdempotencyToken(generateNewToken());
    transactionWriteRequest.addUpdate(idMapping);

    executeTransactionWrite(transactionWriteRequest);
    return idMapping;
}

public void executeTransactionWrite(TransactionWriteRequest transactionWriteRequest) {
    try {
        dynamoDBMapper.transactionWrite(transactionWriteRequest);
    } catch (DynamoDBMappingException ddbme) {
        System.err.println("Client side error in Mapper, fix before retrying. Error: " + ddbme.getMessage());
    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException rnfe) {
        System.err.println("One of the tables was not found, verify table exists before retrying. Error: " + rnfe.getMessage());
    } catch (InternalServerErrorException ise) {
        System.err.println("Internal Server Error, generally safe to retry with back-off. Error: " + ise.getMessage());
    } catch (TransactionCanceledException tce) {
        System.err.println("Transaction Canceled, implies a client issue, fix before retrying. Error: " + tce.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("An exception occurred, investigate and configure retry strategy. Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```